# calling socket bind results in Windows bluescreen

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, ipv6, bsod

We discovered that running our application under certain conditions results in Windows bluescreen. After some investigation we were able to narrow down the scenario to a sample of ~50 lines of C code using Winsock2 APIs. The sample -details removed by MS request-. Windows Server 2008 R2 crashes after several seconds running the sample. The problem reproduces on different physical machines as well as on Virtual Machines.

It looks like something that Microsoft would be willing to fix given that the problem repro is consistent. What is the right way to report such a bug? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just sent a notification to the IPv6 Program Manager for MS Windows

Comment: MS need to look at this but so do you. `size` should be `sizeof sockaddr`, not 28; you have two 0xffs, not one; and I'm not clear about '169.13.13.13 (not configured on the local machine)'. If that isn't an IP address of a local interface you shouldn't be binding to it.

Comment: bind address is a configurable parameter in our app. If someone mistypes it the system keeps crashing [our app is a service :-) ] bind is supposed to return with error, not to crash.

Comment: Two 0xff is all right. The address in the comment is wrong, it should be ::FFFF:169.13.13.13 .

Comment: @EJP - it should be sizeof(sockAddr) (his variable name) or sizeof(sockaddr_in6).  sizeof(sockaddr) is the size of the generic sockaddr type.

Comment: Update: I have been contacted by a Microsoft representative. The problem is likely to be resolved in the nearest future.

Comment: What were Microsoft's reasons for asking you to remove the code?

Comment: EJP: this may be a security bug.

Comment: Ah, things like this happens often in open source bug databases like Mozilla's.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131039/how-much-influence-should-an-external-site-entity-have-over-the-questions-on-a-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just fixed in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-032